# Applying a function (AIC) to elements in a list

Tags: r, list

My goal is to run the function `AIC` on several elements in a list. Here is my code:

```r
library(urca)

set.seed(1234)

df_example <- data.frame(a = rnorm(75), b = rnorm(75), c = rnorm(75))

df_UR_za <- lapply(
  df_example,
  function(x){
    ur.za(x, model = "both")
  }
)

# Problem is here

df_UR_za_AIC <- lapply(
  df_UR_za,
  function(x){
    AIC(eval(attributes(x)@testreg))
  }
)
#> Error in UseMethod("logLik"): no applicable method for 'logLik' applied to an object of class "list"

# Expected result

a_za <- ur.za(df_example$a, model = "both")
a_za_AIC <- AIC(eval(attributes(a_za)$testreg))

b_za <- ur.za(df_example$b, model = "both")
b_za_AIC <- AIC(eval(attributes(b_za)$testreg))

c_za <- ur.za(df_example$c, model = "both")
c_za_AIC <- AIC(eval(attributes(c_za)$testreg))

table_all_results <- data.frame("Variable" = c("a", "b" , "c"), 
                                "AIC" = c(a_za_AIC, b_za_AIC, c_za_AIC))

table_all_results
#>   Variable      AIC
#> 1        a 205.2485
#> 2        b 192.5752
#> 3        c 229.4742
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have made some changes, try next code. It looks the issue was `@`. It is better to use `$` depending of the object:

```
library(urca)

set.seed(1234)

df_example <- data.frame(a = rnorm(75), b = rnorm(75), c = rnorm(75))

df_UR_za <- lapply(
  df_example,
  function(x){
    y <- ur.za(x, model = "both")
    return(y)
  }
)

# Code

df_UR_za_AIC <- lapply(
  df_UR_za,
  function(x){
    AIC(eval(attributes(x)$testreg))
  }
)
```

Output:

```
df_UR_za_AIC

$a
[1] 205.2485

$b
[1] 192.5752

$c
[1] 229.4742
```

Comment: Could you please explain why did you insert ```return(y)```?

Comment: @bttomio Of course, as you are using a function, it is better to always return the result of what you compute. In your case the model can be assigned to `y` and then returned so that the values are stored in the object `df_UR_za`. I hope this is clear enough for you :)

Comment: Yes, it's clear. I was just wondering why it is better to always return the result. Thanks!